How to completely remove a 3way light switch
I have a 3-Way “Master Switch” that controls all of the outlets on the main floor. Is there a way that I can remove both switches so there is no way to turn the outlets off except for the breaker?

Are there lights plugged into the outlets?  Do you have other switches controlling ceiling lights?

None of the lights are plugged into the outlets. I have one switch for controlling the dining room light, a 3way for the front door light, and a 3way for the family room light

There should be a way to remove the switches, but must keep the newly made junction boxes, which must be kept accessible(a blank plate cover).  Which wires to connect together is above my knowledge level.  Some tape or switch locks would be easier.

I'm not following how the "master" switch is behaving in this setup. Does it reverse the state of both the front door and family room lights? Does it affect the dining room light at all?

Yes, there is.
Between the two switched that make up your "3-way master switch", there is a pair of wires that are called the travelers. Identify these at each switch location and hopefully they have different colors.
At each switch location, connect the wire that was on the "common" screw of the switch to a traveler with a wire-nut and cap off the other traveler. Make sure that at both locations you connect to the same traveler.
If done correctly, now your outlets are permanently on. Put in a blank cover where you removed the switches, as those junction boxes need to remain accessible.

If done incorrectly, at some point, you've picked the wrong traveler, so swap that one out and continue.
